# Java create image from RGBA byte array

Tags: java, arrays, image, byte

I am trying to create an image file (format doesn't matter) from a RGBA byte array. The array looks like this: [r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a...]
There are a few things i already tried, for example stb_image. The problem with that is, that i have to allocate a Buffer via MemoryStack, but my array is just too big (around 4 Kb) so it throws a OutOfMemoryException. I also cannot just write it with a ByteArrayOutputStream, since i dont have any headers, just rgba values. Width and height is known tho.

Comment: This is the sort of question I associate with LWJGL and assimp.  See if this solves the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690732/lwjgl-assimp-loading-textures

Comment: How would you derive the image dimensions from that array?

Comment: The dimensions are already there, I dont have to worry about them

Comment: In what kind of environment or context is *"around 4 Kb"* a *big* array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 possible solutions for this:

1. Manually build image file based on it's specification
2. Use some library for image file processing and setup image pixel by pixel.

First way is very fast and efficient by performance, but seems too hard for implementation. Second way is slower, but easier.

There is a class *java.awt.image.BufferedImage* that allows us to work with images. With it's help we can easily build image if we know pixels, width and height of an image. Here is sample code for you:

```java
public static void createImage(int[] colors, int width, int height) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Iterate over array and set image pixel-by-pixel
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i += 4) {
        int row = (i / 4) / width;
        int column = (i / 4) % width;

        int red = colors[i];
        int green = colors[i + 1];
        int blue = colors[i + 2];
        int alpha = colors[i + 3];

        // rgb value is 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 bits, each for r/g/b/a number
        int rgb = (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;

        image.setRGB(column, row, rgb);
    }

    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("result.png"));
}
```

I've tested this method with 2.4mb png image, image creation took 600ms. Not very fastest way to do it, but definitel easy

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage inputImage = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/user/Images/apple.png"));

    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>(); //Initial storage for r g b a

    for (int h = 0; h < inputImage.getHeight(); h++) {
        for (int w = 0; w < inputImage.getWidth(); w++) {
            int pixel = inputImage.getRGB(w, h);

            int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
            int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            int blue = pixel & 0xff;

            colors.add(red);
            colors.add(green);
            colors.add(blue);
            colors.add(alpha);
        }
    }

    int[] colorsArray = new int[colors.size()]; // Transforming ArrayList to int's array
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
        colorsArray[i] = colors.get(i);
    }

    createImage(colorsArray, inputImage.getWidth(), inputImage.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: Thnak you! That works perfectly fine